# Difference Between PDO / Prepared Statement - PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I tried Google to find any disadvantage but did not find any !
I'll be glad if anyone share some thing on this topic !
Advantage/ disadvantage of PDO and Prepared Statement

Edit 2 :

I think everyone want to say **Prepared Statement** is better than **PDO** ?
Am i right ?

Comment: Advantage: Safe, disadvantage: Much code. Solution: Write a small wrapper that gives you the safeness without so much code ;)

Comment: @nikic that was simply wrong.

Comment: @teresko: People feel offended if you just tell them they're wrong ;) It's always better to actually tell why they are ;) Because I honestly can't think of a reason.

Comment: @nikic , you have to make sure that PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES  is set to false, if you want to be sure that the protection against SQL injections is fully functional, and if you do the binding of variables/values right, then the code i much more compact and easier to manage then the mysql/mysqli style.

Comment: @teresko: In that case we'll just need to agree to disagree. In my eyes code using prepared statement is always very bloated (because you need one line for each parameter).

Comment: @nikic: it depends.  Do you care about security?  Because if so, your statement is nieve...  And *much code*?  How much extra code do you write for prepared statements?  Because I find I actually write the same if not less...

Comment: Partial duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5887113/338665

Comment: @ircmaxell: Sorry? Just be sure I understand you right: If I use a small wrapper (similar to what Brad showed in his answer), which utilizes the `PDO->quote` method, you call that insecure? Are you actually telling me, that the `PDO->quote` method is vulnerable? If so, could you please give me some reference? That would mean that all my code is open to sqli!

Comment: @ircmaxell: Oh, and your careers link in your about me text gives me a 404 ;)

Comment: @nikic: Yes. It will be made public soon, but yes, you can still be vulnerable even if you use PDO::quote() (depending upon other things)...

Comment: @ircmaxell: Most interesting. I'm eagerly awaiting publication to see whether this applies to my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major disadvantage to PDO will be it takes a bit more querying time (I cannot "prove" this so don't take it as fact just what I have noticed / read), which is well less then a second. But if you need that extra less then a second `mysqli` offers prepared statements like `PDO` and I believe works a bit quicker given it is set for one database and not many.

It is more code, but as nikic stated, use a wrapper class to setup your statements so your code can look something like:

```
$db->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ?', $name);
```

Where `fetchAll` is a custom function you write to handle the binding of the params etc.

Which would I use? `mysqli` or `PDO` (PDO due to its versatility personally). `MySQL` (not `mysqli`) is kind of outdated, and in the end you could be writing a lot more code using `MySQL` in that you always have to filter the input (as in escape to prevent SQL injections, it will not validate what should be put in there) before putting it into the database. Using prepared statements, the filtering is all done for you and the chance for an Injection is very low as long as it is used properly.

Answer (score 0):

The real big advantage of prepared statements is that the parameters passed in to the ? are checked for validity.  So SQL injection attacks are harder than if you create your sql something like this

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO table VALUES('" & $stringfromForm & "');";
```

as if somecone could set up enter the following into the form

```
x'); INSERT INTO someothertable VALUES ('rubbish
```

then you could be in trouble